# how to send a form to html in django

Tags: python, html, django, forms, post

I am trying to send a form to html using django. this is the form

```
from django import forms

class contactForm(forms.Form):
name = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=100,help_text='100 characters max.')
email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
comment = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea)
```

The view file is

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import contactForm
# Create your views here.
 def contact(request):
   form = contactForm(request.POST or None)

   if form.is_valid():
    print (request.POST)
    context = locals()
    template = 'contact.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

and the html file which is named correctly is,

```
  {% extends 'base.html' %}

  {% block content %}
  <h1> Contact </h1>

   <form method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='submit form' class='btn btn-default'  />
   </form>
   {% endblock %}
```

When you visit the page the only thing that shows up is the h1 tag how do i fix this?

Comment: You need to render form object as well

Comment: where? and how?

Comment: You're always trying to validate the form, even if it wasn't a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
def contact(request):
   form = contactForm(request.POST or None)

   if form.is_valid():
      print (request.POST)
      context = locals()
      template = 'contact.html'
      return render(request, template, context)

   return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: you get this error when trying that ValueError at /contact/
The view contact.views.contact didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: ya need to return outside the if condition in your code your not returning anything .

Comment: I have updated my code. You neet to return render outside the if condition. when you submit your form then only if condition will valid and enters into it otherwise it won't enter. Your "return render..."  is inside the if condition that is the problem

Comment: got this error  File "C:\Users\14153\Desktop\Tradify.com\Tradifycom\contact\views.py", line 13
    return render(request, template, context)
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: return it inside the function outside the if . May be your return statement is outside the function now

Answer (score 0):

The correct format of rendering a from is this:

```
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from . import models
from . import forms

def contact(request):

    if request.POST == 'POST':

        form = forms.contactForm(request.POST or None)
        contact_model = models.contactModel() #err is here name it with appropriate model name contactModel is just an example

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_model.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            contact_model.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            contact_model.comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            contact_model.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')) #desired url to redirect, you can use reverse to call templates according to url names

    else: #if request is GET
        form = forms.contactForm()

     context = {
        'form': form
     }

     template = 'contact.html'
    return render(request, template, context=context)
```

Do not use action in your template, just set your `urls.py` to redirect to the desired view.

Comment: It says that contactForm is not defined.

Comment: because it was just a simple made up model name. You should have to change it to the desired one. I updated the code to make it clearer.